# SWIG error when compiling MPI C code! "undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_int"

Tags: python, c, mpi, swig

I'm trying to compile MPI C code with a SWIG wrapper for Python interfacing. From scouring StackOverflow and google, I know this is an issue with linking during the SWIG wrapping, but I can't figure out a solution to the problem.

I compile with the following lines:

```
>swig -python worker_c.i
>mpicc -fPIC $(python-config --includes) -c worker_c.c worker_c_wrap.c
>ld -zmuldefs -shared worker_c.o worker_c_wrap.o -o _worker_c.so
```

and importing the resulting worker_c.py yields:

```
Python 2.7.2+ (default, Jul 20 2012, 22:15:08)
[GCC 4.6.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import worker_c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "worker_c.py", line 25, in <module>
    _worker_c = swig_import_helper()
  File "worker_c.py", line 21, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_worker_c', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: ./_worker_c.so: undefined symbol: ompi_mpi_int
```

Here is my source code:

**worker_c.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

const int nelements1 = 1E3;
const int nelements2 = 1E6;

int outarray(){
    float* array = malloc(sizeof(float) * nelements2);
    int i = 0;
    for( i = 0; i < nelements2; i++ ){
        array[i] = 1.110001;
    }

    return *array;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

MPI_Comm comm;
MPI_Comm_get_parent(&comm);

int myid, world_size;//, size;
int root = 0;
int* endloop = malloc(sizeof(int));
void* input = malloc(sizeof(float) * nelements1);
void* output;
void* sendbuff;
int recv = 1;

MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

output = (void *)outarray();

MPI_Scatter(sendbuff, recv, MPI_INT, endloop, recv, MPI_INT, root, comm);

while ( endloop[0] < 1) {
    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    MPI_Scatter(sendbuff, recv, MPI_FLOAT, input, nelements1, MPI_FLOAT, root, comm);
    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    MPI_Gather(sendbuff, recv, MPI_FLOAT, output, nelements2, MPI_FLOAT, root, comm);
    MPI_Scatter(sendbuff, recv, MPI_INT, endloop, recv, MPI_INT, root, comm);
}

free(endloop);
free(input);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

**worker_c.i**

```
// file: worker_c.i
%module worker_c
%{
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "worker_c.c"
%}

%include mpi4py/mpi4py.i
%mpi4py_typemap(Comm, MPI_Comm);
void outarray();
void main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

I have little experience with SWIG and MPI, so I'd appreciate any help available.
Thank you!

Comment: When you link the shared object, it doesn't include a reference to the MPI implementation library (Open MPI in your case). You should use the MPI compiler wrapper instead of `ld` to link the shared library.

Comment: Thanks @HristoIliev! I didn't know the MPI compiler wrapper could be used instead of `ld`.

Comment: `mpicc` just wraps around some compiler, e.g. GCC. As long as the latter is able to link standalone object files into executables and shared libraries (possibly invoking `ld` behind the scenes), `mpicc` can too.

Comment: Great, thanks for that explanation @HristoIliev. Unfortunately now I'm just at a daunting segfault error, but I suppose I'll have to make another post for that one.

Comment: You `main()` function is missing a call to `MPI_Init()`. Is MPI initialised somewhere else?

Comment: @HristoIliev MPI is initialised in a Python master file, which spawns this C worker. I shouldn't need to call `MPI_Init()` then, no?

Comment: You need to initialise MPI one for any process that makes MPI calls. If spawning means starting a new process, then yes, you have to call `MPI_Init()`.

Comment: @HristoIliev Alright, that makes sense... I just tried that, though, and it still segfaults. This is the output I get: http://pastebin.com/rS5DF9gi

And backtracing in gdb is fruitless:
`(gdb) backtrace`
`#0  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()`
`#1  0x00007fffffffe662 in ?? ()`
`#2  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`

Comment: Your `outarray()` is returning the first element of the array it allocates inside converted to `int`, i.e. `(int)1.11001`, which is `1`. Then in the `main()` function the return value `1` is converted to `(void *)` and assigned to `output`, then used in various MPI calls. Dereferencing `output` results in the segfault.

Comment: @HristoIliev you should gather all this into an answer I would upvote it, nicely done (even if not total solution, clearly there are many problems with the code).